# Pair iMac and Android using Bluetooth

Tags: macos, bluetooth

I had my uninsured iPhone stolen and have bought a cheap Panasonic Eluga 500 as a makedo until I save up enough for another iPhone. Why can't I pair this phone with my iMac over Bluetooth. I have a truly ancient Nokia that pairs so why not this Panasonic? Are there certain brands that Apple doesn't like?

Comment: When you say pairing, what do you mean? Linking to the computer to transfer files, using the phone as a mobile hotspot, using the computer like a Bluetooth speaker, or something else?

Answer (score 1):

If you open Bluetooth to iMac and iPhone **and also** use the same Apple ID on both, these two device will “automatically” connect to each other.

But the usage of those connections are heavily limited. Here’s some example

- Continuity
- Personal Hotspot

and some few more that I tend to forget.